# Showing there is a node in the graph with one and only one edge

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

We have an undirected simple graph with $n$ vertices where for every pair of vertices $v_1,v_2$, if $d(v_1)=d(v_2)$ then the set of neighbours of $v_1$ is disjoint from the set of neighbours of $v_2$. Assuming the graph contains at least one edge, prove that there is a vertex of degree exactly $1$ in the graph.

For example the following graph has vertices of degree exactly $1$:

[image]

While this problem concerns a graph, I feel like there is a way to apply pigeonhole theory to prove this.  Is this possible?

Comment: I placed some edits with more technical terms to make the question more clear. Do check whether this is really what you meant.

Comment: Wouldn't this be false if the graph consists of $n$ isolated vertices?

Comment: @VTand that's true. But, I guess, the OP is talking about connected graphs only. Can you find a counterexample in connected graphs?

Comment: @VTand but there is at least one edge in the graph

Comment: @SayanDutta i appreciate the edits, thank you

Comment: FYI a graph with this property is called [highly irregular](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_irregular_graph).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $v$ be the vertex of the greatest degree and let $\operatorname{deg}(v)=k>0$.
Let $N(v)$ be neighbors of vertex $v$.
Then the degrees of all vertices from $N(v)$ are pairwise distinct,
and if there are no vertices of degree 1 among them,
then there must be a vertex of degree $k+1$ or more.
This contradicts the choice of vertex $v$.

Comment: Does this assume the graph is connected?

Comment: It is enough to assume that there is at least one non-isolated vertex.