# Showing there is a node in the graph with only one edge

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I saw this question recently, [Showing there is a node in the graph with one and only one edge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323480/showing-there-is-a-node-in-the-graph-with-one-and-only-one-edge) and I am just wondering how the approach would be different if we added the following restraint:
We have an undirected simple graph with n vertices where for every pair of vertices $v_1,v_2$, if $d(v_1)=d(v_2)$ then the set of neighbours of $v_1$ is disjoint from the set of neighbours of $v_2$ **where there may be an edge between $v_1$ and $v_2$**. Assuming the graph contains at least one edge, prove that there is a vertex of degree exactly 1 in the graph.

Comment: Did I understand your condition correctly?
If vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ are adjacent
and $d(v_1)=d(v_2)$, then $N(v_1)\cap N(v_2)=\varnothing$.
Or is it not?

Comment: More formally, we can say that if vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ are adjacent and $d(v_1) = d(v_2)$, then $(N(v_1) - v_2) \cap (N(v_2) - v_1) = \emptyset$. Otherwise, if vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not adjacent and $d(v_1)=d(v_2)$, then $N(v_1) \cap N(v_2) = \emptyset$

Comment: The wording of your bold phrase, "where there may be an edge between $v_1$ and $v_2$", as clarified in your Comment, should be cleaned up in the body of the Question.  You should exclude the case $v_1 = v_2$ (otherwise the graph would have no edges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there'll be no different. You mean that $v_2\in N(v_1)$ and $v_1\in N(v_2)$ is allowable. While $v_1\notin N(v_1),$ $v_2\notin N(v_2),$ $N(v_1)\cap N(v_2)=\varnothing$ is still right.